# Prevent Unknown WiFi network from showing in windows 10/11 laptop

Tags: networking

Is there a way to prevent unknown wifi network or specified the selected wifi network using bat file? We are trying to configured it from GPO but it is not working (Domain), on the local side there is no IEEE policy available.

**We would like to show 3 of our company network, we want to prevent the non-company network inside company premises.**

Anyone knows how??

Thank you!

Comment: *prevent the non-company network inside company premises* prevent what? prevent from being seen? prevent from being used? prevent the signal even being present?

Comment: @Jaromanda X From being seen/show

Answer (score 2):

On what PC's? Since you state you tried this with GPO, I assume it's for Windows. [Create a batch file](https://www.techbout.com/hide-block-wifi-networks-windows-38797/) using *netsh wlan add filter permission...* to allow or disallow access.

- First, whitelist the open corporate networks you wish most users to use, e.g., with SSID's of *WiFi 1* and *WiFi 2*, adding each:

  ```
  netsh wlan add filter permission=allow ssid="WiFi 1" networktype=infrastructure
  netsh wlan add filter permission=allow ssid="WiFi 2" networktype=infrastructure
  ```
- Then forbid all other networks:

  ```
  netsh wlan add filter permission=denyall networktype=infrastructure
  ```

Of course, anyone close enough to your facility could use another computer on which that script *had not* been applied to access other corporate networks. Such a script might deter an employee from casually accessing a forbidden network, but provides no security. More effective would be to use [more secure WiFi protocols](https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/feature/Wireless-encryption-basics-Understanding-WEP-WPA-and-WPA2).

Comment: Its Windows 10 PC. We will try this, thank you very much. 

Where can I contact you then for follow up questions and/or concern regarding this??

Comment: How do I start the bat file? should I start with ECHO??? Sorry too many questions, this is my first time creating a bat file :<

Comment: This site is not a script writing service, though is can help with *specific* questions. Look at any of the many online tutorials on writing Windows batch scripts, e.g., https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/ or https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-run-batch-file-windows-10 . If the answer is useful, please mark it as accepted; there's no need to contact the author, though. If you find additional issues, rather, edit the question to include them.